# Windowed functions do not support constants as ORDER BY clause expressions in SQL Server TempTable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, window-functions, row-number

This is my dynamic SQL query:

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM 
                (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY '+ @sortBy +') AS rowNumber FROM #temp) A 
            WHERE A.rowNumber BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(varchar(9),
(@startIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + ' AND ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), 
(((@startIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1)+''

print(@SQL)
exec(@SQL)
```

And this is the output of the `PRINT` command:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
   (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Typename) AS rowNumber       
    FROM #temp) A 
WHERE A.rowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

where `Typename` is the `@sortBy` parameter value.

But I get this error:

> Windowed functions do not support constants as ORDER BY clause
>   expressions.

Comment: is [Typename] a column in the temp table at that time?

Comment: @Used_By_Already: yes

Comment: can you post the structure of `#temp`

Comment: @Used_By_Already,@ ughai: when i tried with  [Typename] (included square bracket) it worked.why it was not worked without square bracket

Comment: wondered if that might be the case, it forces it to treat it as a column name. You may want to use **...VER(ORDER BY '+ QUOTENAME(@sortBy) +') AS ..**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest you use QUOTENAME(@sortBy) within the string concatenation, this will ensure the local variable's content s valid as a column name.

Comment: How can i pass column name+ asc/desc on this context?

Comment: use an additional local variable perhaps? like this
**...VER(ORDER BY '+ QUOTENAME(@sortBy) +' ' + @sort_direction + ') AS ...**

Answer (score 1):

This may not the solution, but if it helps..

> Windowed functions do not support constants as ORDER BY clause
>   expressions.

This error normally observed when you try to have a `constant value` in `ORDER BY clause of a windowed function`

like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 'const_val')`